# Generic type-Object type mismatch in java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, declaration, type-mismatch

I tried to create a LinkedList class. But I had 2 problem:

1)The `Node last=null` declaration is giving me a raw-type error but in above of that declaration there is no error like it. 4 same declarations but only the last one gives an error.

2) In the `get()` method I want to return V type and as you can see the value variable is already in V type. But it gives me "cannot convert Object to V" error. But temp.value is already V.

```
public class Linkedlist<V> {

    public class Node <V> {

        private Node next=null;

        private String key;

        private int size;

        private V value=null;

        public Node(V value, String key){
            this.key=key;
            this.value=value;
        }
    }

    Node root=null;
    Node temp=null;
    Node temp1=null;
    Node last=null;

    last=root;

    public void add(V value, String key){
        last.next = new Node(value,key);
        last=last.next;
    }


    public void remove(String key){
        temp=root;
        if(isEmpty())
        System.out.println("list is empty!");

        else{
            if(temp.next!=null){

                if(!temp.next.key.equals(key)){
                    remove(temp.next.key);
                }

                else if(temp.next.key.equals(key)){
                    if(temp.next==last)
                    last=temp;
                    temp.next=temp.next.next;
                }
            }
            else
            System.out.println("there is no such element");
        }
    }


    public V get(String key){
        temp=root;

        if(temp.key.equals(key)){
            if(temp.next!=null)
            get(temp.next.key);

            else
            return null;
        }
        else if(temp.key.equals(key))
        return temp.value;

    }
```

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation of your code. It is very hard to read.

Comment: I am a newbie in coding. Sorry for everything that make you suffer while you are reading. Also sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner class `Node` is generic, but you're using the raw form of the class.  That means that a method that returns `V` gets type-erased, and it is now returning `Object`.  But the `Node` class doesn't need to be generic.  A non-`static` nested class (i.e. a nested class) can use its enclosing class's generic type parameter.  So, remove the `<V>` on the `Node` class definition.

```
public class Node {
```

Other problems I see:

- `last=root;` appears to be outside any constructor, method, or initialization block.
- I don't see an `isEmpty()` method, but you may have not posted it for brevity.
- The `get()` method needs a `return` statement in the case that neither the `if` nor the `else` conditions are met.

Comment: not to mention the `else if` block in the `get()` method has the exact same condition as its initial `if`, therefore is unreachable code

Comment: Erasing <V> from Node class helped and thanks for that. However i tried to declare variables in the constructor but other methods didn't see the variables. I must make them global. How can i do that?
Additionally, isEmpty() method exist but i don't want to copy it to here.

Comment: Variables declared in a constructor are local variables that are only in scope in the constructor body.  You can make them instance variables, as you have already done for `root`, `temp`, `temp1`, and `last`.

Comment: When i do what you said, it is giving me a raw-type error that i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Without knowing what local variable you're making an instance variable, it's difficult to say.  I don't see any local variables in your `Node` constructor.

Comment: I talked about
Node root=null;
    Node temp=null;
    Node temp1=null;
    Node last=null;
declarations.
You suggested me to put them into a method or constructor. But i want to make them global if i put them to a constructor or a method they will be local variable. Outside of all method, they are giving me raw-type error. How can i make them global and dont take any error?

Comment: No, only the statement `last=root;` needs to be in a method, constructor, or initialization block.  The declarations of the instance variables for `Linkedlist`, e.g. `Node root=null;`, are fine where they are.  And if you removed the `<V>` on the `Node` class declaration, then you shouldn't get a raw type error, because `Node` is no longer generic.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend. Thanks your patient to read that bad-written code and try to understand my terrible english.

Answer (score 0):

The two problems you cite are really one and the same.  Given a parameterized class `Node<V>` such as you declared, these ...

```
Node root=null;
Node temp=null;
Node temp1=null;
Node last=null;
```

... all declare objects of the raw type `Node`.  Other code will interpret treat them as if their type parameters had been specified as `Object`.  You should instead declare them like so:

```
Node<V> root=null;
Node<V> temp=null;
Node<V> temp1=null;
Node<V> last=null;
```

where the `<V>` is literal -- a reference to the class's type parameter, not any concrete type.  If you do that then both your errors will go away.

Comment: I tried it but that did not change anything. I took another error. Also i erased <V> from Node class after rgettman's suggestion and it helped to get rid of "convert object to V" error.